# TravisCI/Docker support: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am receiving the following error while trying to start a Docker image from by Travis build:

```
41.39s$ docker pull zopyx/existdb-22
latest: Pulling from zopyx/existdb-22
Status: Downloaded newer image for zopyx/existdb-22:latest
before_install.2
13.75s$ docker pull zopyx/existdb-30
latest: Pulling from zopyx/existdb-30
Status: Downloaded newer image for zopyx/existdb-30:latest
8.90s$ docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:22081:8080 --name existdb22 zopyx/existdb-22
143fb4d9226f46361aa36ce4f2c5144b491d66b00801c9f5af4247d80edd1d96
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 143fb4d9226f46361aa36ce4f2c5144b491d66b00801c9f5af4247d80edd1d96: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.1 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before, it was an issue related to the default docker version pre-installed (1.7.0) and updating fixed it.

You can upgrade to an image running an updated Docker version by adding the following lines to your .travis.yml file:

```
group: edge
```

Does this help? Feel free to reach at support@travis-ci.com

Comment: Their update to Trusty and latest Docker 1.8.2 also helped as well.